# #if DEBUG equivalent in SQL Database Projects?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, configuration, debug-symbols

I am trying to / wondering if you can have environment-specific coding in an SQL Database Project, particularly in the **PostDeploymentScript.sql**

I know it would be possible to add SQL server environmental-specific code in the .sql file but I was wondering more along the lines of how you would do a C# compile-time statement, such as `#if DEBUG { }`?

This would be, say, if a DEBUG configuration had values differing from RELEASE but were the same no matter what SQL Server it were being deployed to.

[Here's a mock-up example of what it would look like in my head, if it worked](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jitKk.png)

Comment: Have a look at the "SQLCMD Variables" section of your project properties

Comment: @gvee, SQLCMD variables don't appear to be environment-specific.

Comment: @RogerWolf create a SQLCMD variable called, for example, "Environment". Then when you run SQLPackage.exe (presumably by your CD pipeline) you can supply it the _value_ with `/Variables:Environment=dev` and for your next stage `/Variables:Environment=test` etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that SSDT does provide functionality for customising deployments, by the means of `DeploymentPlanModifier` extensions. [Here might be a good starting point](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/use-deployment-contributors-to-customize-database-build-and-deployment) to delve into the subject.

After briefly skimming through the help topic, however, I have a suspicion that this particular functionality is only available if you use DACPAC deployment for your projects. It might not work if your preferred deployment method is the generation of change scripts via the Schema Compare tool. That, and the amount of C# code that needs to be written is, how shall I put this, looks almost prohibitive.

Barring that, the simplest solution I see is to use a dedicated SQLCMD variable which would control the deployment logic. However, that means you and your team would have to change its value before any deployment to an environment other than the default. Unless you will find a way to completely automate this process, eventually people will start making mistakes.

Comment: Thank you for this @Roger - it was this kind of handling I was hoping to avoid (with regards to env vars).

I guess if there is no viable solution I will have to live with that fact :-)